# Webview2 AdditionalBrowserArguments --Kiosk-printing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, arguments, webview2

I'm trying to print using the Webview2 control.

I can print with a dialog using the follwing code:

```
 Await WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();")
```

But i would like to print silently.
With Edge we can use the parameter --Kiosk-printing like in Chrome.

This is the property i'm looking for: [CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions.AdditionalBrowserArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2environmentoptions.additionalbrowserarguments?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.818.41#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions_AdditionalBrowserArguments)

But how can i start the Webview2 control using these parameters?

I've looked up some examples like this: [Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/193)
But converting them to VB.NET using https://converter.telerik.com/ doesn't seem to work.
Is it possible using WinForms?
Thank you for your time!

This is what i have so far:

```
    Dim opts As New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions With {.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--kiosk-printing"}
    Dim env As CoreWebView2Environment = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing), opts)
    Dim tsk As Task = WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)
```

But is giving me the error:  'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
And i dont know how to use this could somebody please give me an example?

**UPDATE**

This is the current code that i have but it's not working.

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Await InitializeAsync()
End Sub

Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task

Dim opts As New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions With {.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--kiosk-printing"}
Dim env = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, opts)

AddHandler WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2.FrameNavigationCompleted, AddressOf WebView_Browser1_FrameNavigationCompleted
Await WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)
End Function

Private Sub WV_CoreWebView2Ready1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

I don't know how to use the arguments with my WebView_Browser1.
Can somebody please give me an example of how do deal with this?
Thank you!

Comment: `dim options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("--proxy-server=""ProxyName:Port""") dim env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, options) await [WebView2 Instance].EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)`

Comment: Thank you! But where do i place this in the Form_load? and the  await CoreWebView2Environment is giving me the error: 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Mark the 'Form_load' eventhandler with `Async` too.

Comment: You need to use an `Async` method. Which method, depends on where / when you initialize a WebView2 instance. If you use a Form, then override `OnLoad()` or even subscribe to the `Load` event; make any of these methods `Async`. Event handlers can be `void` (a `Sub`), no need to return a Task .

Comment: Your `Form1_Load` handler needs to be `async`, then you can `await InitializeAsync()`, declared as `Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task`. You cannot await `void` (a `Sub`), except in an event handler. -- The parameters of `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync()` are clearly wrong.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Jimi! I've updated the question again with your recommendations, but i'm still struggeling. Could you please give me a full example?

Comment: It's all in the first comment, why didn't you follow it? `Await WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` needs to be called last, as `Await WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)`, that's where you pass the `CoreWebView2Environment` object. -- `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync()` is still wrong: call it as `Dim env = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, opts)`. -- Also test `--kiosk --kiosk-printing`

Comment: I'm sorry but this is my first time dealing with this. I've edit the post again and i feel were really close! It gives an error on this line  Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task because i've not openend the Sub. Can you please guide me through this last stage? Thank you so much!

Comment: You have `Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task [...] End Sub`, which you must of course change to `End Function`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233014/discussion-between-desz-and-jimi).